# Unable to uninstall Sql Server 2012 Express (With SP1)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, installation, windows-10

**My Stack:**
. Windows 10 Enterprise
. SQL Server 2012 Express (*with SP1 bundled*).

**ISSUE:**
. Installed SQL to test for backward compatibility.
 
. When I tried to ***Un-Install*** the following prompt is thrown.

[image]

**Attempted Resolution Step:**
. uninstalling individual components.
 
. re-installing SP1 for that edition.

*None of these steps have worked. One last resort was to delete registry entries and then reattempt to delete.*

Any ideas?

Comment: This is bug in SQL Server which has already been informed via [This  connect item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/707706/unable-to-uninstall-sql-server-2012-rc0-from-control-panel) see workaround mentioned. Please also check [this MSDN thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c2bb8040-02f3-4fc7-ad3e-77241e65fe0b/uninstall-sql-express-2014-error?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade)

Comment: This post is for a different version and edition, but brute force may be an approach too: https://sqlblog.org/2010/10/25/fun-with-software-uninstalling-sql-server-2008-r2-evaluation-edition

Comment: Yes it probably has to result to brute force. Once attempted i'll post an update. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A month later, I need to test with a full version of SQL locally but remembered I had this pain in the a** to deal with.

**TO RESOLVE:**

1. Change SQL compatibility mode to **"Windows Vista SP1/SP2"**. Go to where it was installed. Path belows for x64 version. For 32x it will be in the ~\program Files (86) directory. 
   ***C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\SQLServer2012***
    
   [image]
2. Launch CMD, run as an Administrator. Navigate to the directory above.
3. Type command **Setupup.exe /action=uninstall**
4. Follow the prompts.
5. **Find your life ~ Shaun T** :)

Comment: Who is "Shaun T"?

Comment: @Erik: Perhaps some unknown DBA aspiring to become a celebrity in the SQL or SQL Server world, and iamfobbs may thus be helping them.

Comment: Hahaha funny. His a sports performance trainer I get training inspiration from. "Find your life" is a term he coined that sort of means get better at what you do.  if you are into fitness check out "beachbody.com" and have a look at Insanity. Find your life :)